# Referencing one array to make changes in another given certain conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, called `arr1`, example `[9, 0, 0 ,9, 9]`. I made a copy of this and called it `arr2`. I am trying to add the value one (`1`) to certain indexes in `arr2`, dependent on the index position of `arr1` and it being a nine (`9`).

For example,

```
if arr1[0] == 9, add one (1) to indexes [0], [3], [4] in arr2  
if arr1[3] == 9, add one (1) to indexes [0], [2], [3] in arr2  
if arr1[4] == 9, add one (1) to indexes [0], [1], [4] in arr2
```

So `arr2` becomes `[12, 1, 1, 11, 11]`.

Hope this makes sense, bear with me, I'm new to this.

Cheers.

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: your statements almost match the code required ... `if (arr1[0] == 9) {arr2[0]+=1; arr2[3]+=1; arr2[4]+=1; }`

Comment: I don't see the logic. Why would the second statement need to add one to the value at index 2? What is the reasoning?

Comment: [What's this for?](https://xyproblem.info/) Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @outis you summarised it will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is what achieves your task.

```js
var arr1 =  [9, 0, 0 ,9, 9];
         var arr2 = [...arr1]; // create a copy or a clone or array one
         if(arr1[0] == 9){
            arr2[0] += 1;
            arr2[3] += 1;
            arr2[4] += 1;            
         }

         if(arr1[3] == 9){          
            arr2[0] += 1;
            arr2[2] += 1;
            arr2[3] += 1;            
         }

         if(arr1[4] == 9){
            arr2[0] += 1;
            arr2[1] += 1;
            arr2[4] += 1;            
         }

         console.log(arr2)
```